# How do I make gapless audio work when using the mplayer audio output on gmusicbrowser?

Tags: sound

First I uninstalled mplayer and replaced it with mplayer2 since it is supposedly capable of gapless playback.

Now I know gtstreamer can do gapless but some of my files have glitches when using the gtstreamer option in the audio preferences of Gmusicbrowser which is why I am using the mplayer option instead. Now what exactly do I put in the options box to make playback gapless on gmusicbrowser using mplayer2?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the gapless option (-gapless-audio) in SMplayer2 doesn't work. So probably it (the same command) won't work in Gmusicbrowser as well.

I've tried all of the Linux music players, but only those consistently support gapless playback:

- DeadBeef
- Auqualung
- Audacious
- MPD
- XMMS2

Adding the Gstreamer developer PPA solves the gapless issue in Guayadeque and may do so in Gmusicbrowser as well. Guayadeque got better by the way, and it's better than GMB.

You can find the Gstreamer developer PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~gstreamer-developers/+archive/ppa).

Enter in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gstreamer-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Then launch Synaptic and on the left click *Status*, then click Installed (upgradable) and upgrade all the gstreamer related packages. I've left one of them asking to remove many other packages. Installed others and closed Synaptic.

Then Update manager itself asked to upgrade the one I've left un-upgraded before. Updated this as well accepting the *remove gnome-media* warning.

No problem so far. Guayadeque plays gaplessly now.

Answer (score 1):

Gapless audio in gmusicbrowser using mplayer2 works just fine on my end. Here are the steps I followed to get it working:

First, you will need to get the latest build of mplayer2. MOTU media maintains such packages for Oneiric and Precise. Run these commands to add them to your sources:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:motumedia/mplayer-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mplayer2
```

Next, start gmusicbrowser and open "Settings". Go to the "Audio"-tab, and choose mplayer. To enable gapless playback, press the "advanced options" button and enter "-gapless-audio".

That should do it!